# Grunt task to assemble JSON files from filenames in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I have a JSON file that looks like:

```
{
    "someRandomStuff": "myRandomStuff",
    "includeNodesFromFiles": {
        "item1": "item1.json",
        "item2": "item2.json",
        "item3": "item3.json"
    }
}
```

And now I want to replace item1, item2, and item3 with JSON content from each respective file, so the destination file would look like:

```
{
    "someRandomStuff": "myRandomStuff",
    "includeNodesFromFiles": {
        "item1": {"whatever": "...whatever was in item1.json"},
        "item2": {"whatever": "...whatever was in item2.json"},
        "item3": {"whatever": "...whatever was in item3.json"},
    }
}
```

Or similarly for an array:

```
{
    "someRandomStuff": "myRandomStuff",
    "includeNodesFromFiles": [
        "item1.json",
        "item2.json",
        "item3.json"
    ]
}
```

To:

```
{
    "someRandomStuff": "myRandomStuff",
    "includeNodesFromFiles": [
        {"whatever": "...whatever was in item1.json"},
        {"whatever": "...whatever was in item2.json"},
        {"whatever": "...whatever was in item3.json"}
    ]
}
```

How could I do that with Grunt? I'm not finding a Grunt task that will do that out-of-the-box so far.

New to Grunt, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** This is a very custom requirement and there are no existing grunt plugins which will achieve this that I'm aware of.

---

#### Solution:

You'll need to create your own grunt plugin to handle this type of requirement. The following steps describe how this can be achieved:

1. Firstly create a plugin file as follows. Lets name the file `json-replace.js`:

   **json-replace.js**

   ```
   /**
    * Custom grunt plugin replaces JSON values (filepatha) with JSON file content.
    */
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

     'use strict';

     var path = require('path');

     /**
      * Custom grunt multi task to replace values in JSON.
      */
     grunt.registerMultiTask('jsonReplace', 'Replace values in JSON', function() {

       // Read the configuration values.
       var src = this.data.src;
       var dest = this.data.dest;
       var keyName = this.data.key;

       var baseDir = path.dirname(src);

       // Default options
       var opts = this.options({
         indent: 2
       });

       /**
        * Determines whether the passed value is an Array.
        * @param {*} value - A reference to the value to check.
        * @returns {Boolean} - true if the value is an Array, otherwise false.
        */
       function isArray(value) {
         return Array.isArray(value);
       }

       /**
        * Determines whether the passed value is an Object.
        * @param {*} value - A reference to the value to check.
        * @returns {Boolean} - true if the value is an Object, otherwise false.
        */
       function isObject(value) {
         return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]';
       }

       /**
        * Reads a file's contents, parsing the data as JSON.
        * @param {String} srcPath - The filepath to the JSON file to parse.
        * @returns {Object}- The parsed JSON data.
        */
       function readJson(srcPath) {
         return grunt.file.readJSON(srcPath);
       }

       /**
        * Writes JSON data to a file.
        * @param {String} destPath - A filepath for where to save the file.
        * @param {Object|Array} data - Value to covert to JSON and saved to file.
        * @param {Number} [indent=2] - The no. of spaces to indent the JSON.
        */
       function writeJson(destPath, data, indent) {
         indent = (typeof indent !== 'undefined') ? indent : 2;
         grunt.file.write(destPath, JSON.stringify(data, null, indent));
         grunt.log.writeln('Saved \x1b[96m1\x1b[0m file');
       }

       /**
        * Checks whether a file exists and logs any missing files to console.
        * @param {String} filePath - The filepath to check for its existence.
        * @returns {Boolean} - true if the filepath exists, otherwise false.
        */
       function fileExists(filePath) {
         if (!grunt.file.exists(filePath)) {
           grunt.fail.warn('Unable to read \"' + filePath + '\"');
           return false;
         }
         return true;
       }

       /**
        * Checks whether type of value is a string and logs an error if not.
        * @param {*} value - The value to check
        * @returns {Boolean} - true if type of value is 'string', otherwise false.
        */
       function isString(value) {
         if (typeof value !== 'string') {
           grunt.fail.warn('Value type must be a string: found \"' + value + '\"');
           return false;
         }
         return true;
       }

       /**
        * Processes each Array item for a given key.
        * @param {Object} data - The parsed JSON data to process.
        * @param {String} keyName - Name of key whose Array values to process.
        * @param {String} baseDir - Base directory path of the source json file.
        */
       function processArrayItems(data, keyName, baseDir) {
         var replacement = [];

         data[keyName].forEach(function(item) {
           var fullPath = path.join(baseDir, item);

           if (isString(item) && fileExists(fullPath)) {
             replacement.push(readJson(fullPath));
           }
         });
         data[keyName] = replacement;
         writeJson(dest, data, opts.indent);
       }

       /**
        * Processes an Objects key/value pair for a given Object.
        * @param {Object} data - The parsed JSON data to process.
        * @param {String} keyName - Name of key whose property values to process.
        * @param {String} baseDir - Base directory path of the source json file.
        */
       function processObjectValues(data, keyName, baseDir) {
         var replacement = {};

         Object.keys(data[keyName]).forEach(function(key) {
           var accessor = data[keyName][key];
           var fullPath = path.join(baseDir, accessor);

           if (isString(accessor) && fileExists(fullPath)) {
             replacement[key] = readJson(fullPath);
           }
         });

         data[keyName] = replacement;
         writeJson(dest, data, opts.indent);
       }

       // Read the source JSON file
       var srcData = readJson(src);

       // Check if the `key` provided exists in source JSON.
       if (!srcData[keyName]) {
         grunt.fail.warn('Missing given key "' + keyName + '" in ' + src);
       }

       // Invoke the appropriate processing for key value.
       if (isArray(srcData[keyName])) {
         processArrayItems(srcData, keyName, baseDir);
       } else if (isObject(srcData[keyName])) {
         processObjectValues(srcData, keyName, baseDir);
       } else {
         grunt.fail.warn('Value for "' + keyName + '" must be object or array');
       }

     });
   };
   ```
2. Save `json-replace.js` in a folder named `custom-grunt-tasks` which resides in your projects root directory (i.e. at as the same level as `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json`). For instance:

   ```
   .
   ├── Gruntfile.js
   ├── custom-grunt-tasks    <---
   │   └── json-replace.js   <---
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   └── ...
   ```
3. Add the following Task to your `Gruntfile.js`:

   **Gruntfile.js**

   ```js
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

     grunt.loadTasks('custom-grunt-tasks');

     grunt.initConfig({
       jsonReplace: {    // <-- Task
         targetA: {      // <-- Target
           src: 'path/to/source.json',
           dest: 'path/to/output/file.json',
           key: 'includeNodesFromFiles'
         }
       }
       // ...
     });

     grunt.registerTask('default', ['jsonReplace']);
   }
   ```

   **Notes:** (regarding configuration of *Gruntfile.js* above)

   - The line which reads `grunt.loadTasks('custom-grunt-tasks');` loads the custom plugin (i.e. `json-replace.js`) from the directory named `custom-grunt-tasks`.
   - A Task named `jsonReplace` is added to `grunt.initConfig({...})` which contains one [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) arbitrarily named `targetA`.
   - The value for the `src` property should be replaced with a valid filepath which points to your source `.json` file.
   - The value for the `dest` property should be replaced with a filepath for where the new `.json` file should be saved.
   - The value for the `key` should be replaced with a valid keyname. The name of the key provided should be for the key which holds either an Object or Array of `.json` filepaths (For example; `includeNodesFromFiles`, as given in your two examples)

---

**Additional info:**

1. `json-replace.js` is [multi-taskable](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks) which basically means you can configure multiple Targets inside the `jsonReplace` task if required. For example:

   ```js
   // ...
   jsonReplace: {    // <-- Task
     targetA: {      // <-- Target
       src: 'path/to/source.json',
       dest: 'path/to/output/file.json',
       key: 'includeNodesFromFiles'
     },
     targetB: {      // <-- Another Target
       src: 'path/to/another/source.json',
       dest: 'path/to/output/another/file.json',
       key: 'anotherKeyName'
     }
   }
   // ...
   ```

   Multiple Targets may be useful if you want to process multiple `.json` files.
2. `json-replace.js` expects the value of the `key` (e.g. `includeNodesFromFiles`) to be either:

   - An Object with nested key/value pairs, (as per your first example), whereby each nested key has a filepath value for an existing `.json` file.
   - Or, an Array, (as per your second example), whereby each item of the Array is a filepath value for an existing `.json` file.
   - *Note: An error will be logged to the console if the structure of the given JSON `key` does match either of the two aforementioned structures.*
3. `json-replace.js` indents the content of the resultant `.json` file(s) using two spaces by default. However, if you want to change this you can utilize the `indent` option. For example the following Task configuration will indent the resultant `.json` file by four spaces:

   ```js
   // ...
   jsonReplace: {
     options: {
       indent: 4  // <-- Custom indent option
     },
     targetA: {
       src: 'path/to/source.json',
       dest: 'path/to/output/file.json',
       key: 'includeNodesFromFiles'
     }
   }
   // ...
   ```

---

> **Important:** *When defining the filepath values in the source `.json` file (e.g. `item1.json`, `item2.json` etc) this solution expects them to be relative to the source `.json` file itself.*

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple task with just loading file and change value in object(all file paths are relative to `gruntfile.js`):

```
    grunt.registerTask('mytask', 'My super task', () => {
        // file with json with file paths
        //{"someRandomStuff":"myRandomStuff","includeNodesFromFiles":{"item1":"item1.json","item2":"item2.json","item3":"item3.json"}}
        let main = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myjson.json', 'utf8'));
        Object.keys(main.includeNodesFromFiles).forEach((key) => {
            main.includeNodesFromFiles[key] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(main.includeNodesFromFiles[key], 'utf8'));
        });
        //... do some stuff
        grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(main)); //{"someRandomStuff":"myRandomStuff","includeNodesFromFiles":{"item1":{},"item2":{},"item3":{}}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. It recursively replaces filenames with files, if they exist. Also accepts a base URL for the files to be included:

```
grunt.registerTask('buildJson', function(name) {

    let config = grunt.config.get('buildJson'); // Get the config options from gruntInitConfig for our task.
    let options = name ? (config[name] || config) : config; // If there isn't a config option that matches, use the object itself

    function genJson(path, baseUrl = '') {

      function checkIfFile(fPath) {
        try {
          if (fs.lstatSync(fPath).isFile()) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'ENOENT') {
            return false;
          } else if (e.code == 'ENAMETOOLONG') {
            return false;
          } else {
            console.error(e);
          }
        }
      }

      var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, {
        encoding: 'utf8'
      }));

      return JSON.stringify(json, function(key, value) {
        if (checkIfFile(baseUrl + value)) {
          return JSON.parse(genJson(baseUrl + value));
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      }, 2);
    }

    let files = grunt.file.expand(options.srcFiles);

    for (let file in files) {

      let srcPath = files[file];
      // Determine the output path to write our merged json file.
      let outputPath = path.join(options.destDir, path.basename(srcPath));
      let destJson = genJson(srcPath, options.baseUrl);

      grunt.file.write(outputPath, destJson); // Write to disk.

    }

  });
```